# Frequent kernel panics always accompined by severe graphical glitching. Is my machine possessed or in need of a new motherboard?

Tags: gnome, kernel, ati, xorg, memtest

Ubuntu 14.04

I'm having incredibly frequent kernel panics that have been getting worse for the last week, after I installed and then removed Gnome and GDE.  At this point, it is almost impossible to work on the machine, as it dies at least within five minutes of booting, if not sooner.  I assume it's all panics, but about 50% of the time, it dies without a panic screen.

Sometimes, it just goes into a hard reboot, sometimes, the screen blacks out and it does not want to restart, after killing these, the machine will not load the bios until the power is cut for ~5 seconds. Otherwise, it will display a panic screen, which at this point almost always is shredded or somehow corrupted graphically, with garbage pixels stranded or the text smeared across the screen.  If left to sit, the graphical glitches will occasionally change or flash.  The panics themselves are often different, some "tried to execute MX-protected page', some "CPU: 1 PID: 0 Tainted", some "CPU: 0 PID: 0 Not tainted", etc.

Always accompanied by some manner of graphical glitching, either moments before it crashed or while it's frozen or while it's displaying the panic screen or some combination of all the above.  Most frequent glitch is as if the screen is broken into vertical bars spanning each an 8th of the screen, which are then rearranged. Other 'shredding' of the screen is frequent.

ATI Radeon 200M
Always, compiz and xorg have been resource hogs, normally taking at least 20% cpu each.  I can boot from the recovery screen, but it still experiences crashes.  Cannot do the full failproof mode, it hangs.  Will crash when booted from CD, leading me to believe it's hardware.   Memtest crashed after 2% pass two out of two times.  The second time it was oscillating between looking normal and displaying random text shredded over the normal memtest screen.  The flashing red plus continued to flash but everything else was frozen.

Once out of the fifty-some times it's displayed a panic screen, it was complaining about the stuff it wrote to swap being corrupted, but that's never happened again.

I am at a total loss.

Comment: This appears to be a thermal issue, or bad memory, or a graphic card's issue. Remove dust, check all fans if they are alive, re-attach cables.

Comment: I know it's not thermal - I'd gone through that song and dance before, and I'm familiar with the signs there.  Also, sensors gets run a lot.  I pulled out the RAM in anticipation of buying more, and then it passed Memtest after ~10 hours (5 minutes earlier it failed on some 50-odd dropped bits), and it's been running perfectly ever since, leaving me confused.

Comment: yeah - bad RAM can cause the weirdest issues but you appear to have found the issue now :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing sounds more like a hardware issue instead of a software one.  I would verify that all heatsinks are properly attached to your machine first.

Then I would remove/swap/replace ram, until you are able to pass memtest.

Once you are able to pass memtest, then you can start worrying about Ubuntu.  Fyi, memtest is fully independent of Ubuntu.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Problem with hardware issues is that they cost money.  Meh.